# Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "profesor.post" when trying to display posts that belong to currently logged user in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring and I have application where profesors can post their posts. I am trying to display all posts that belong to one profesor who is currently posting them or who is currently logged in. Between profesor and posts classes I have bidirectional relationship one-to-many I am trying to achieve it like this:

**profesor.java**

```
@Entity
public class Profesor extends User {

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "profesor",  fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Post> post;
//getters and setters

}
```

**post.java**

```
@Entity
public class Post {

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn (name="profesor_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)

    private Profesor profesor;
    //getters and setters
}
```

and I am trying to display it like this

**index.html**

```
<tr th:each="post : ${profesor.post}">
 <td class="message" data-th-text="${post.message}"></td>
```

I got this error in my console

```
EL1008E: Property or field 'post' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.ArrayList' - maybe not public?
```

or this one in browser

```
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "profesor.post"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try fetch = FetchType.EAGER.

Only then will the data be fetched every time, if as you have done, the FetchType.LAZY will not fetch until you access them, here you're not accessing them.

But be careful when using EAGER, since the query will become slower.

http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-eager-loading

This has some information.

These are my entity classes:

```
public class Professor implements Serializable {

@Id
private String id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "professor", fetch = EAGER)
private List<Post> posts;
}

@Entity
public class Post implements Serializable {

@ManyToOne
private Professor professor;
}
```

Check it out, it should work. If not, may be we need a bit more of your code.

Comment: @dome have made an edit to my answer, with the code that I just wrote. This works for me.